# unicode text being modified in python unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I want to read an file with unicode data, do some processing and write in another file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import codecs


def main(big_filename, small_filename):

    print "Big file ", big_filename
    print "Small file ", small_filename
    pattern1 = u'CreationDate="2008'
    pattern2 = u'CreationDate="2014'

    small_f = codecs.open(small_filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    small_f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n')
    small_f.write("<posts>\n")

    cnt = 0
    big_f = codecs.open(big_filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    for line in big_f:
        #line = line.decode('utf-8')
        if line.find(pattern1) != -1 or line.find(pattern2) != -1:
            small_f.write(line)
            cnt = cnt + 1
            if cnt%1000:
                print cnt, " records written"

    small_f.write("<\posts>\n")        
    small_f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Text in big_filename

```
Other hardware architectures fall back to the system’s timer, which is typically set to 100 Hz.
```

And text in small_filename

```
Other hardware architectures fall back to the systemâ€™s timer, which is typically set to 100 Hz.
```

But I see, some unicode exts are modified in the small_filename. Can somebody tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: Uh... which file is the first and which is the second?

Comment: Can you provide the hex dump of both files around the position of the backtick symbol?

Comment: the question is modified for proper filename and I have copied the complete sentence where the data is getting modified. The file is the xml dump of stackoverflow questions. The header looks like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Answer (score 0):

Strings inherently contain the `encode` method. Try this:

1. Read small file and dump as variable like so: `small_read = open(small_filename).read()`
2. Overwrite the file with a new blank file: `small_file = open(small_filename, 'w')`
3. Write with codecs exactly as you did:

   `small_f = codecs.open(small_filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
   small_f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n')
   small_f.write("<posts>\n")`
4. Now write the file contents with utf-8 encoding like so:

   `small_file.write(small_read.encode('utf-8'))
   small_file.close()`

Comment: I can't read the entire file and dump as a variable. It's 30 GB.

Comment: Try to compress it with zlib or implement Huffman encryption.